# How to delete other people Repository on Github home page?

Tags: github

Open https://github.com/ ,I see other people Repository occur on my Github home page?

[image]

I'm not watching, forking, staring, and no settings page of the repo.
[image]

How should I delete it? I am new to Github.

Comment: try deleting from the settings page of the repo

Comment: No settings page.